# .net RestSharp Deserialization: custom field name

Tags: c#, .net, deserialization, restsharp

I'm trying to deserialize the following object:

```
{
    "start_time": "2013-05-21T10:58:32Z", 
    "result": 1, 
    "message": " ok", 
    "operator": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/2/"
}
```

How to write a C# model of this object? The "operator" keyword cannot be used as model name and I haven't found any Attribute that can be used in order to map the name.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At a guess:

```
public class SomeType {
   public DateTime start_time {get;set;}
   public int result {get;set;}
   public string message {get;set;}
   public string @operator {get;set;}
}
```

The `@` prefix can be used to escape any C# keyword; `@int`, `@string`, `@for` etc.